# Mongoose and express router issue with more than one get

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-router

Good morning everyone,

I'm stuck in this problem and I can't find a way to solve. I think is really easy to but I can't find the error. I'm just trying to create 3 routes with express to get all active tournaments, just one selected with the parameter and the latest 3 for the home page.
For that, I have created three gets to fetch the data with different functions in my controller. But if I try to fetch the data with postman of the route "/activetournament" I receive this error. The only way to remove it is comment the other 2 gets. Thank you for your answers.

```
(node:17203) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "activetournaments" at path "_id" for model "Tournament"
```

```
const tournamentsCtrl = {};

const Tournaments = require("../models/Tournaments");

tournamentsCtrl.createTournament = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const newTournament = new Tournaments(req.body);
    await newTournament.save();
    res.json({ message: "Tournament Saved" });
}


tournamentsCtrl.getTournament = async (req, res) => {
    const tournament = await Tournaments.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(tournament);
}

tournamentsCtrl.homeTournament = async (req, res) => {
    const tournament = await Tournaments.find().sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(3);
    res.json(tournament);
}

tournamentsCtrl.actTournament = async (req, res) => {
    const tournament = await Tournaments.find({ "signup_dates.signup_end_date": { $gt: new Date() } });
    res.json(tournament);
}

module.exports = tournamentsCtrl;
```

```
const router = require("express").Router(); // Enrutador
const tournamentsCtrl = require('../controllers/tournaments.controller');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

//Create tournaments
//api/tournaments
router.post('/', tournamentsCtrl.createTournament);
router.get('/activetournaments', tournamentsCtrl.actTournament);
router.get('/:id', tournamentsCtrl.getTournament);
router.get('/', tournamentsCtrl.homeTournament);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is not the issue with router. It is problem with tournaments.controller or service. Please provide more details/code from which request you are facing issue

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post with the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After observing your controller and routes code, I found where problem lies.

```
router.get('/activetournaments', tournamentsCtrl.actTournament);
router.get('/:id', tournamentsCtrl.getTournament);
```

For express.js, above two routes works as same, where in second route, in place of `:id`, it considers `activetournaments`, and proceeds further. So, when you hit API `/activetournaments`, it calls two routes

1. router.get('/activetournaments', tournamentsCtrl.actTournament);
2. router.get('/:id', tournamentsCtrl.getTournament);
   And your getTournament method accepts id and that id comes from req.params, which is in this case `activetournaments`. 

   Solution for this problem is, use different convention to create routes such as,

```
router.get('/activetournaments', tournamentsCtrl.actTournament);
router.get('/tournamentById', tournamentsCtrl.getTournament);
```